# Only allow access view from specific view

Tags: python, pyramid

I have registered two views:

```
config.add_route("home", "/home")
config.add_route("home/data", "home/data")
```

`/home` view has some Javascript code in the frontend that will fetch data from `home/data`

What is proper way to allow the access `home/data` if users access website via: `mysite.com/home`?

I tried to check `request.referer` but, it seems easy to modify/hack.

Comment: What's the goal? If the page can access it client-side, the user can access it directly.

Comment: hmm, I only want client-side users to access home/data to limit requests

Comment: You're going to need some kind of anti-DDOS and/or anti-scraping system in place (which is usually out of scope in the context of a web application). (I hear Cloudflare offers a service that is good at this kind of thing.) Locking one url to another (assuming it could be done) just means they'll fetch the available one and extract the data they want, making the problem worse.

Comment: If you just want to limit requests, some web server softwares have options to rate limit by ip. I don't know the details, but it's something to look into.

Answer (score 0):

Let `H(m)` be a function that hashes a message, perhaps SHA3.

Create a secret `S` which only your webserver knows.

The `/home` page will have a link to `home/data`.
Change that link each time you display the page.
The HREF should include a pair of query parameters:

- `time` is current timestamp, e.g. seconds since 1970 epoch
- `nonce` is `H(S + time)`

The `home/data` page should report a permission error if

- the pair of parameters is missing, or
- the `time` is not a fresh timestamp, or
- the `nonce` doesn't validate.

So we have one page producing links to a data page,
and those links are the *only* way to retrieve the data contents.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the main issue. Retrieving the data via automation would still be near trivial.